# Possible to iterate through foreach and keep only matching value? (using CodeIgniter)

Tags: codeigniter, foreach, loops

I'm trying to compare the libraries of books of two users. I am displaying another user's library, and I would like for there to be a link to "Ping" under the book if the current user also has that book in his library.
Here is the relevant controller code:

```
function other_user_library()
{
    $this->load->model('user_library_model');
    $this->load->model('user_information_model');
    $data['other_user_library']=$this->user_library_model->other_user_library($username);
    $data['my_book']=$this->user_library_model->compare_libraries();

    $this->load->view('other_user_library', $data);
}
```

Here is the model:

```
function other_user_library($username)
{
    $this->load->database();

    $this->db->select('*');
    //rest of query to display all of other user's books

    $query= $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();    
}
function compare_libraries()
{
    $this->load->database();

    $this->db->select('BOOK.isbn');
    //rest of query to return the current user's list of isbns in his library

    $query= $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();    
}
```

And here's the relevant View code:

```
<?php foreach ($other_user_library as $row) :?>
<?php if($row->isbn)
    {
       foreach ($my_book as $thing):
       if($thing->isbn ==$row->isbn)
       {
           $ping = TRUE;
           if($ping)
           {
             echo anchor('Ping');
           } 
       }
       else
       {
          echo "somethingelse";
       }
       endforeach;  
       }?>              
   <?php endforeach;?>
```

Now, as it stands, for a user who has 8 books, one of which matches the book in the other user's library, this will display "somethingelse" 7 times and then the "Ping" link once. I am wondering if there is a way just to go through the 8 isbns, see that ONE of them matches, and then just display the "Ping" link. I have tried just removing the else{echo "somethingelse";} line. And then it displays just the "Ping" for the matching books. However, I would like to be able to put something else under those books that do not match, as opposed to just leaving them blank. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't follow your entire code. But I've made changes to where I see need for obvious modifications. Give it a try.

```
 <?php foreach ($other_user_library as $row) : ?>
        <?php
         $ping = FALSE; //set ping here
        if ($row->isbn) {


            foreach ($my_book as $thing):
                if ($thing->isbn == $row->isbn) {
                    $ping = true;
                    break; //prevents the continuous loop after a match incase you have thousands of rows
                }

            endforeach;

            if ($ping) { //Do the echo after this point to have just one echo. You could still move out of the parent foreach loop as long as $ping is defined first.
                echo anchor('Ping');
            } else {
                echo "somethingelse";
            }
        }
        ?>              
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Well, even though you didn't understand my code, you answered my question. It's working. Thanks very much.

Comment: I would certainly be glad to, but I tried to, and the website told me that I need at least 15 reputation in order to vote up anything. So, hopefully someone who reads this could give the vote up for me?

Comment: I'm new here too. I just started answering questions and got 76 reputation. It just made me glad. I'm happy you tried too. I'm also trying to understand the SO system. I seem to enjoy it. I should have been answering questions all these while. Thanks!